# Try to access third party website in IOS AIR app (as3)

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air

I've made an AIR App for Android and IOS. The app is taking infos from my database and displays it. (with URLRequest and loader)

```
var urlReqSearchAll: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.brousse-en-folie.com/cinenc/searchMovie4.php");
var loader5:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
```

It also saves images from a website into the phone :

```
uiloader1.source = http://www.cinecity.nc/images/image.jpg;
uiloader1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, movie1Complete);

function movie1Complete(event:Event):void {
    movieImage1 = movieImage1.resolvePath("movie1Image.jpg"); 
    chooseTheOne = movieImage1;
    stream.load(new URLRequest(products[0].movieimage)); 
    stream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, writeComplete); 
    uiloader1.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, movie1Complete);
}

 function writeComplete(evt:Event):void  { 

            var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
                var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
                stream.readBytes(fileData,0,stream.bytesAvailable); 
                fileStream.openAsync(chooseTheOne, FileMode.UPDATE);
                fileStream.writeBytes(fileData,0,fileData.length); 
                fileStream.close(); 
        }
```

Everything is working fine on Android devices but on IOS my app seems to not retrieve the information.

I've added in the XML file of the IOS this :

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>cocogeek.nc</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
         <key>brousse-en-folie.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
      <key>cinecity.nc</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
   </dict>
```

But even with that, it doesn't work.

Any idea what I've forgot ?

Comment: Where `Android` doesn't care, it's possible that `iOS` doesn't like that your app is receiving external data from a non-secure `http` location. I would test if this is a `http` -vs- `https` issue. For example can you load a **.txt** file (of copied JSON) and display within AS3 text box? I mean load one copy from current `http` location an load other **.txt** from `https` location (_ie:_ free DropBox account). Which one worked / displayed / parsed?...